# Menu Bar with Login Link

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a Menu Bar with a Login Link/Button on the menu bar. Can I use a ASP Menubar to achieve this?
I used a Menubar item & a button. But they appear in 2 separate lines. Is it possible to combine them on the same line?

[Like so:](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/2430/menubar.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a solution. Was pretty simple too. Used a table with 2 columns. Dropped the menubar in the 1st column & the Login Linkbutton in the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.orientation%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), the default orientation is vertical